# Using AwesomeMenu with a UITabBarController tabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have been playing around with adding an AwesomeMenu button to my UITabBar. My plan is to have the icons arc above the tab bar with looks pretty cool. I have played with it a bit and have been able to get the icons to display. I to call the menu, I just used the same button that I already had, added an AwesomeMenu behind the tab bar (so the icons bounce up from behind) then hid the Awesome menu. I added an action to my button in the tab bar to simulate a tap on the awesome menu, as well as show the AwesomeMenu, which then shows the buttons perfectly. The problem is that when I try to tap on any of these button, nothing happens. I assume that this is a problem because they are above the UITabBar, but I cannot be sure. I have added a normal AwesomeMenu in the middle of a blank view controller with the same set up as I have on the tab bar (except being on a tab bar and being called by another button) and it works. When I press a button, they work. Based on this, I figure that it is a problem with the buttons being displayed above the UITabBar or maybe simply the way the buttons work. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is how I add the button to the UITabBar (pretty standard):

```
UIImage *storyMenuItemImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Fill.png"];
    UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[storyMenuItemImage CGImage] scale:(storyMenuItemImage.scale * 2.0) orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    UIImage *storyMenuItemImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Fill.png"];

    UIImage *starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Camera_Fill"];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem1 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Camera_Fill"]
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem2 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Video_Fill"]
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];


    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem3 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Pen"]
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];

    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem4 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];

    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem5 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector_Music_Fill"]
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    // the start item, similar to "add" button of Path
    AwesomeMenuItem *startItem = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-addbutton.png"]
                                                       highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-addbutton-highlighted.png"]
                                                           ContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-plus.png"]
                                                highlightedContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-plus-highlighted.png"]];
    startItem.center = CGPointMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.center.x , 30);

    //22
    self.menu = [[AwesomeMenu alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) startItem:startItem optionMenus:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:starMenuItem1, starMenuItem2, starMenuItem3, starMenuItem4, starMenuItem5,nil]];
    self.menu.startPoint = CGPointMake(160.0, 22.0);
    self.menu.rotateAngle = M_PI / 180 * -60;
    self.menu.menuWholeAngle = M_PI / 180 * 120;
    self.menu.timeOffset = 0.036f;
    self.menu.farRadius = 140.0f;
    self.menu.nearRadius = 110.0f;
    self.menu.endRadius = 120.0f;
    self.menu.delegate = self;
    self.menu.hidden = YES;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:self.menu];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar sendSubviewToBack:self.menu];
```

Here is how I call it from the button in the UITabBar:

```
[self.menu touchesBegan:nil withEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a UIButton into the Tabbar which triggers to initialize an empty view containing all the AwesomeMenu stuff. You can pass the touch event from the button to the awesome menu with `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. Don't forget to dismiss the ViewController when `-(void)awesomeMenuDidFinishAnimationClose:(AwesomeMenu *)menu`. You also have to pass the selected MenuItems though a delegate to the parent vc.